# Is there a way to run two or more python modules simultaneously from Eclipse(pyDev)?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am in the process of building a system in python that centralizes the compilation of our code to a set of machines. I have all three programs written, running and working; however I'm still trying to weed out some of the more elusive bugs. I have been mostly testing over the localhost interface and therefore run all of the components on my machine.

Is there a way to run all the components simultaneously in one Eclipse session so that I can flip between them and terminate if needed?

I have been using multiple terminal windows, but since the code is still immature, it's not always possible to exit cleanly from the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just run them as normal and use the Console menu to flip between them. If you run them under the debugger, you can also use the Debug view in the Debug perspective to terminate them - in either case, using the red square icon to do the terminating.

Comment: Also, you can create new instances of the console and pin the run you want in each console.